# Sum hours and minutes in a column in Openoffice Calc 4.1.1

Tags: time, openoffice-calc

This is quite a tricky question.

I'm trying to sum the hours and minutes in a column.

I need it to show either in the format `[HH]:MM` (hours:minutes) or `DD HH:MM` (days hours:minutes).

I've tried the `=SUM()` function but it work well. It shows as `04:30`, instead of the real value.
I've also tried other tricks (like other formats) and even some custom functions.

All the columns have the format `HH:MM`.

Here is the structure of the table:

[image]

I'm sorry about my terrible Paint skills. The 'hidden' part is just text. All those columns are introduced manually.
Where you see `=SOMA(D7:D37)`, is where I want the time showing.
`=SOMA()` is the equivalent of `=SUM()` for English versions. I'm using the Portuguese version.

Comment: How did you enter the values in col B and C? Obviously, D is the result of C-B, and it's crucial to know which are the values you've entered there.

Comment: @tohuwawohu As I said in the question, they are introduced manually.

Comment: Sorry, but i wasn't able to reproduce this with LO Calc 4.4.0.3. I suppose it's a matter of formatting the cells. `04:30` is completely fine as sum of those cells, *assuming it's `04:30 PM`* or *`16:30` as absolute value*. So, i assume calc is calculating correctly, but the result isn't formatted in the way you're expecting it.

Comment: @tohuwawohu I found what is going on. I will post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that ALL cells were formated as text (format `@`) at first, prior to the `HH:MM` format.

This placed the formula `'00:30` (notice the first character).

Clicking on the cell and removing it worked as intended.

Example:

[image]

The bad value is on the left, the good one is on the right.

**Lesson:**

Be *very* careful when changing formats.